# interactively call SAS script (server based) from server based Python or vice-versa

Tags: python, server, sas

I am trying to call SAS script using server based Python in my organization. SAS I have access is server based as well but have not been able to configure initial setting. When I import saspy and run sas=saspy.SASsession(), I get following error:

```
Using SAS Config named: default
The OS Error was:
No such file or directory

SAS Connection failed. No connection established. Double check your settings in sascfg_personal.py file.
```

Attempted to run program `/opt/sasinside/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/bin/sas_u8` with the following parameters:`['/opt/sasinside/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/bin/sas_u8', '-nodms', '-stdio', '-terminal', '-nosyntaxcheck', '-pagesize', 'MAX', '']`

If no OS Error above, try running the following command (where saspy is running) manually to see what is wrong:

```
/opt/sasinside/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/bin/sas_u8 -nodms -stdio -terminal -nosyntaxcheck -pagesize MAX
```

> Using SAS Config named: default
>   SAS Connection failed. No connection established. Double check your settings in sascfg_personal.py file.

Attempted to run program `/opt/sasinside/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/bin/sas_u8` with the following parameters:`['/opt/sasinside/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/bin/sas_u8', '-nodms', '-stdio', '-terminal', '-nosyntaxcheck', '-pagesize', 'MAX', '']`

Try running the following command (where saspy is running) manually to see if you can get more information on what went wrong:

```
/opt/sasinside/SASHome/SASFoundation/9.4/bin/sas_u8 -nodms -stdio -terminal -nosyntaxcheck -pagesize MAX
```

But, even when i submit the above command, I do not get any details.
Being able to run python script from SAS will serve my purpose as well, but I am not sure how to do this as well.

Comment: You're likely better off asking these questions on communities.sas.com where the SAS developers can answer it directly. SASpy doesn't have a huge usage at the moment so you're less likely to find people on here to answer your questions.

Answer (score 0):

When you say SAS is server based, do you mean a remote server, not a local installation of SAS? Have to read the configuration guide to see how to configure saspy to get to your remote server? https://sassoftware.github.io/saspy/install.html#configuration
There is more than one way, depending upon your client and server setup.